# Java code automated documentation /presentation

Tags: java, documentation, creation

Is there a tool to create from custom Java code documentation similar to what you can find on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)?

By this I mean listing in a clear way: methods of a class, different types of fields, inheritance, interfaces it implements etc. I want to do this for a library I created. I'm aware that all this information could be found inside the code, but sometimes you don't have time to open every single source file. Preferable html output.

Answer (score 4):

have a loot at [the javadoc tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html). it generates exactly this html from javadoc comments and source code.